# ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH on Android Emulator WebView

Tags: android, ssl, android-webview

I'm debugging an Android app that makes a HTTPS connection to a server. On my physical device this works fine, but on a Genymotion emulator, I get the following error message:

Webpage not available

The webpage at https:// could not be loaded because:

net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

The emulator only has the Android browser(com.android.browser) and not Chrome. Browsing to the URL in the Android browser produces the same error. I then installed Chrome from the Play store, and browsing to the URL in Chrome was successful, but the app still shows the same error.

I've tried disabling the Android browser and setting Chrome as the default browser but still get the same error.

Is the default browser not supporting some TLS version (1.2/1.3 perhaps?). Is there a way to force support?

Comment: Hey, i'm face with the same issue, do you succeed to to connect?

Comment: Unfortunately not.